# Import precedence consistency?

Tags: python

I'm confused about precedence when importing modules and how can I change it.

current directory does contain:

```
l10n/__init__.py
l10n/moneyfmt.py
```

another directory (different then current) with an extra package does contain:

```
/opt/l10n/__init__.py
/opt/l10n/utils.py
```

Now running python interactive interpreter:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11.egg-info']
>>> import l10n.utils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named utils    # CORRECT, NOT IN PATH YET
>>> sys.path.insert(0, '/opt')
>>> sys.path
['/opt', '', '/usr/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11.egg-info']
>>> import l10n.utils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named utils    # WHY IT CAN NOT FIND THE MODULE?
```

Why it can not find the package with l10n.utils module after I did prepended the full path to the search path in sys.path ? Does the current directory *always* takes the precedence here ? Can it be changed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two modules named `l10n`. The first time you try to `import l10n.utils`, the wrong `l10n` is on the path. I suspect this wrong `l10n` is getting cached by the Python shell, and is consulted when you try to `import l10n.utils` the second time (irrespective of the change you've made to `sys.path`).

Try restarting the Python shell, changing `sys.path` as the first thing, and doing `import l10n.utils` right away.

Comment: Wow, if I omit the first import attempt it does load the `l10n.utils` module properly ! Is there some documentation concerning the caching for imports ? Can it be somehow cleared later ?

Comment: @DavidUnric: There is, see http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement and http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. Still find it a bit surprising behaviour.

Comment: DavidUnric: The caching is a reasonably common source of surprises, especially during interactive sessions.